# Question about the Kähler structure on generic coadjoint orbits

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, coadjoint-orbit

Let $G$ be a compact connected Lie group. We denote by $\mathfrak{g}$ the Lie algebra of $G$ and by $\mathfrak{g}^*$ the dual space of $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\mathcal{O}_r: = G\cdot r$ be a generic coadjoint orbit of $G$.

The coadjoint orbit $\mathcal{O}_r$ endowed with the Kirillov–Kostant–Souriau $\omega$ is a symplectic manifold.  I've read that it is also a Kähler manifold; meaning that there exists a unique almost complex structure $J$ on $\mathcal{O}_r$ which is compatible with $\omega$ and such that the form $g(\cdot,\cdot):= \omega(\cdot,J\cdot )$ is a Riemannian metric on $\mathcal{O}_r$.

> Given an element $\beta \in \mathcal{O}_r $, then the tangent space of $\mathcal{O}_r$ at $\beta$ is $T_\beta \mathcal{O}_r = \lbrace  \xi_{\mathcal{O}_r}(\beta), \xi \in \mathfrak{g}\rbrace$ , where $\xi_{\mathcal{O}_r}(\beta) = \frac{d}{dt}\rvert_ {t=0} e^{-t \xi}\cdot\beta$.
> What is  $J(\xi_{\mathcal{O}_r}(\beta) )$, $\xi \in \mathfrak{g} $ ?

Comment: Does 'generic' in "generic coadjoint orbit" have a technical meaning here?

Comment: @LSpice, yes it means that the stabilizer $G_r:= \lbrace g \in G, g.r =r \rbrace $  is a maximal torus of $G$.

Comment: Ah, [OK](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430926/question-about-the-kähler-structure-on-generic-coadjoint-orbits#comment1108949_430926).  I am used to "strongly regular semisimple" in that context.

Comment: I'm also a little confused by your description of $T_\beta\mathcal O_r$, which seems to make no reference to $r$.  Are you sure it's correct?  (At least $\beta$ should be an element of $G\cdot r$, not just of $\mathfrak g^*$.)

Comment: @LSpice,  you are right $\beta$  should be an element of $G.r$, I'll fix that!  However the description of $T_\beta \mathcal{O}_r$ is correct.

Comment: I just find the article called "Coadjoint orbitopes". In page 6  the authors say that more details about the unique kähler structure on  coadjoint orbits (as described in my question), can be found in page 113 of the book "In infinite dimensional kähler manifold". Even though I understood  the answer of @LSpice,  I would like to know more. Could any one please summarize what is in page 113 in that book, since I don't have  access to it ?

Comment: [It](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430926/question-about-the-kähler-structure-on-generic-coadjoint-orbits#comment1109937_430926) seems to be on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Infinite_Dimensional_K%C3%A4hler_Manifolds/hY0HCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA113).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $T = G_r$.  We may, and do, assume that $\beta = r$, and simply describe a $T$-invariant complex structure on $\operatorname T_{\mathcal O_r}(r)$.

Instead of having one 1-dimensional subspace of $\mathfrak g$ for every root $\alpha$, we get a $2$-dimensional subspace $\{X_\alpha + \overline{X_\alpha} \mathrel: X_\alpha \in (\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C})_\alpha\}$ for every pair of roots $\{\alpha, \overline\alpha = -\alpha\}$.

Our Kähler structure treats this $2$-dimensional space, which I will provocatively call $\mathfrak g_{\pm\alpha}$ since its complexification is $(\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C})_\alpha \oplus (\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C})_{-\alpha}$, as a $\mathbb C$-vector space *via* the (isomorphic) projection to $(\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C})_\alpha$, and then rotates by $i$—but we must choose $i$ appropriately to get a negative definite metric.  After our discussion in the comments, I think I have finally cleaned up the relevant signs.

Fix a root $\alpha$ of $T$ in $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$.  Put $i_\alpha = -\lambda\lvert\lambda\rvert^{-1}$, where $\lambda = r(\mathrm d\alpha^\vee(1))$ ($H_\alpha \mathrel{:=} \mathrm d\alpha^\vee(1)$ is sometimes called the coroot, but I prefer to reserve that terminology for $\alpha^\vee$ itself), so that $i_\alpha$ is a square root of $-1$.  Then $J$ carries $\xi_{\mathcal O_r}(r)$, where $\xi = X_\alpha + \overline{X_\alpha}$, to $\xi'_{\mathcal O_r}(r)$, where $\xi' = i_\alpha(X_\alpha - \overline{X_\alpha})$, for every $X_\alpha \in (\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C})_\alpha$.

Comment: I realize now that I don't know why is the metric $g$ definite positive. 
Here is my attempt:  suppose that we are in the simplest situation where $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C}= \mathfrak{t}_\mathbb{C} \oplus {(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C})}_\alpha  \oplus {(\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C})}_{-\alpha} $. Let $\xi= X_\alpha + \overline{X_\alpha} $.  Let $<.,.>$ an Ad-invariant inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: Then, $g_r(\xi_{\mathcal{O}_r}, \xi_{\mathcal{O}_r})=  \omega(\xi_{\mathcal{O}_r}, J(\xi_{\mathcal{O}_r}))=<H_r, [\xi,J(\xi)]> = -2i<[H_r, X_\alpha],\overline{X_\alpha}>= -2i\alpha(H_r)<X_\alpha,\overline{X_\alpha}>.$ From here I don't know how to continue , any help please!

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1109297)$\newcommand\l{\overline}\newcommand\p[2]{\langle#1,#2\rangle}$, $\alpha(H_r)$ is non-$0$ pure imaginary, and $\p{X_\alpha}{\l{X_\alpha}}=\p{s X_\alpha}{s\overline{X_\alpha}}=\lvert c\rvert^2\p{\l{X_\alpha}}{X_\alpha}=\lvert c\rvert^2\l{\p{X_\alpha}{\l{X_\alpha}}}$, where $s$ is a representative in $G$ of the reflexion in $\alpha$ and $c$ is the non-$0$ complex number such that $s X_\alpha$ equals $c\overline{X_\alpha}$.  So the pairing is either positive definite or negative definite.  If it's negative definite, then take $-J$ instead.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430926/question-about-the-kähler-structure-on-generic-coadjoint-orbits/430935#comment1109305_430935) issue (of maybe having to change the complex structure after the fact) can be fixed by choosing the square root $i$ of $-1$ carefully.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: .@LSpice, Could you please explain How to use that $<X_\alpha, \overline{X_\alpha}>={\vert c \vert}^2 \overline{<X_\alpha, \overline{X_\alpha}>}$ in the proof that $g$ is definite positive, I didn't get the idea!

Comment: You are [right](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1109342).  My [argument](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1109305) shows that $\langle X_\alpha, \overline{X_\alpha}\rangle$ is real, but not that it is positive.  I will think about it.  (TeX note: please use $\langle\rangle$ `\langle\rangle` instead of $<>$ `<>`; compare the spacing in $\langle X, Y\rangle = 0$ `\langle X, Y\rangle = 0` to the spacing in $<X, Y> = 0$ `<X, Y> = 0`.)

Comment: Continued from my [previous comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1109354). The Killing form on the Lie algebra of a compact group is negative definite ([e.g.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829205)), so $2\langle X_\alpha, \overline{X_\alpha}\rangle = \langle X, X\rangle$ is strictly negative, whenever $X = X_\alpha + \overline{X_\alpha}$ with $X_\alpha \ne 0$.  (Example: $X = \begin{pmatrix} & i \\ i \end{pmatrix} \in \mathfrak{su}_2$, with the trace pairing.)  So I guess I needed one more sign change.

Comment: .@LSpice, sorry for asking a lot of (stupid) questions, but I didn't understand why is $ 2 \langle   X_\alpha , \overline{X_\alpha} \rangle = \langle  X , X \rangle (= ? \langle  X_\alpha , {X_\alpha} \rangle +  \langle \overline{X_\alpha} , \overline{X_\alpha} \rangle +2 \langle X_\alpha, \overline{X_\alpha} \rangle ). $ Also, $G$ in my question is not necessarily semisimple.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1109374), these latest questions are standard, but not stupid. (I was careless with positive definiteness, so it pays to ask!) $T$-equivariance of the inner product implies $T_{\mathbb C}$-equivariance, which implies that $\langle X_\alpha, X_\alpha\rangle$ is $0$ (conjugate by an element $t \in T_{\mathbb C}$ for which $\lvert\alpha(t)\rvert \ne 1$), and similarly for $\overline{X_\alpha}$. The space $\mathfrak g_{\pm\alpha}$ is not changed by passage to the adjoint quotient, so you may assume that $G$ is semisimple (I should have said explicitly).

Comment: .@LSpice, doesn't $\langle X_\alpha, X _ \alpha \rangle = 0$ implies that $X_\alpha=0$ and then that $ \langle X_\alpha, \overline{X_\alpha} \rangle =0$ ? But I think Now I fully understand your answer using your  the $G$ invariance of the inner product and your proof that $\langle X_\alpha, \overline{X_\alpha} \rangle $ is real. Thank you very much for your great help :)

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1109506)$\newcommand\g{\mathfrak g}\newcommand\C{{\mathbb C}}\newcommand\p[2]{\langle#1,#2\rangle}$, no, the Killing form is negative definite on $\g$ (so we could conclude from $\p XX=0$ that $X=0$ for $X\in\g$), but not on $\g_\C$ (so we cannot conclude from $\p{X_\alpha}{X_\alpha}=0$ that $X_\alpha=0$ for $X_\alpha\in(\g_\C)_\alpha$).  Again, consider the trace form on $\mathfrak{su}_2$, with $X=\begin{pmatrix}&i\\i\end{pmatrix}$, so $\p XX=-2$; but $X_\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}&i\\0\end{pmatrix}$, so $\p{X_\alpha}{X_\alpha}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

For the affine case for coadjoint orbits of Souriau, see Jean-Louis Koszul book "Introduction to symplectic geometry" in chapter 4 and 5 where it is explained the Souriau cocycle in cas of non null cohomology:
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-13-3987-5